# Back button has been created in AppDelegate, how to use it for back action?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I have created back button in AppDelegete. Also I have created a navigation controller (customized). On that navigation bar this back button appears. So it appears on all of my views. But i dont know how to give back action for that, so When I press "back" button it should go to the previous page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this method in your AppDelegete

-(void)gotoBack:(UIViewController*)pViewController
{

```
[pViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

and call gotoback method in your controller like this

[AppDelegete gotoBack:self];

Comment: what is that pViewcontroller? I have nearly 12 view controllers

Comment: pass your viewcontroller in pViewcontroller which you want to pop.

Comment: "error"
No known class method for selector back.
Help plz @yen

Comment: use only [AppDelegete gotoBack:self]; in your controller which want to back.

Comment: On back button you have to call like this              -(IBAction)gotoBack:(id)sender
{
 [ClsHelper gotoBack:self];
}

Answer (score 0):

if only wants to navigate back, Add this target to your navigation back button and no need to create navigation back method, it will call navigation controller’s popViewController selector

```
[_backButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```